# Partitoning table based on year criteria of datetime field

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package that executes a stored procedure and stores its results as a table FinancialStatementIds in the destination database. The table already exists in the destination database. I need to partition the destination table and have written a script to do that.

I am fetching information for the last five years and storing each partition based on the year. So I have created 5 partitions which excludes primary partition and the partition is set to the column periodenddate which is a datetime field. Could you please verify that it is correct. Do I need to add any other column in the partition table

I would also like to know how does the script know that it has to partition the FinancialStatementIds table

**Destinaton table**

[image]

```
USE CoreReferenceStaging;  
GO  
-- Adds four new filegroups to the CoreReferenceStaging database  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT1;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT2;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT3;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT4;
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT5;


-- Adds one file for each filegroup.  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata1,  
    FILENAME = 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata1.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT1;  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata2,  
    FILENAME = 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata2.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT2;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata3,  
    FILENAME = 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata3.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT3;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata4,  
    FILENAME = 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata4.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT4;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata5,  
    FILENAME = 'E:\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata5.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT5;  
GO  

-- Creates a partition function called financialStatementPartition that will partition a table into four partitions  
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition (datetime)  
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (year(getDate()), year(getDate() -1), year(getDate() -2),year(getDate() -4)) ;  
GO  
-- Creates a partition scheme called financialStatementRange that applies financialStatementPartition to the five filegroups created above  
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange  
    AS PARTITION financialStatementPartition  
    TO (CT1, CT2, CT3, CT4,CT5) ;  
GO  
-- Creates a partitioned table called FinancialStatementPartition that uses financialStatementRange to partition periodenddate  
CREATE TABLE FinancialStatementPartition (periodenddate datetime PRIMARY KEY)  
    ON financialStatementRange (periodenddate) ;  
GO
```

DDL for table financialstatementIds

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds](
    [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
    [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
    [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
    [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
    [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
    [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `RANGE RIGHT` when partitioning on a temporal type that has a time component. This will ensure dates that exactly match the partition boundary are placed in the desired partition and filegroup.

The date calculation expressions for the partition function boundaries are incorrect. You should use `DATEADD` instead of subtracting an integer from the current date, which is interpreted as subtracting days.

The script below will create the partition function and scheme for year boundaries 2013 through 2018 (assuming run during 2017), which includes the boundary for the future 2018 year. A best practice with sliding window partitioning is to plan as to split empty partitions to avoid expensive data movement during split (logging is about 4 times that of DML) and the empty future year partition will ensure no data are moved when that empty partition is split in advance of loading data into the partition. This script assumes all filegroups and underlying files already exist.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition (datetime)  
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ();
--the first permanent partition (always empty) 
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange  
    AS PARTITION financialStatementPartition  
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); 
DECLARE @periodenddate datetime = DATEADD(year, -4, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, '', GETDATE()), ''));
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT1;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT2;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT3;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT4;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT5;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
--create partition for future 2018 year
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
            NEXT USED CT6;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
            SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
```

I don't understand the purpose of the `FinancialStatementPartition` table or why it is partitioned.  To partition the `dbo.FinancialStatementIds` table, you can create a partitioned clustered index. The screen shot of that table doesn't include the existing indexes, which are important details to perform this task. Add the actual `CREATE TABLE` DDL with indexes and constraints to your question for clarity.

Note that the clustered index key must include the partitioning column as part of the key. Also, all unique indexes, including primary key and unique constraints, must include the partitioning column as part of the key in order for the indexes to be aligned.

The example below will partition the heap by creating a clustered index.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.FinancialStatementIds(datetime) 
            ON financialStatementRange(periodenddate);
```

To partition the heap and keep existing data, instead of creating a partitioned clustered index, create a new partitioned table table with the same schema but different name, load using INSERT...SELECT, drop the old table, and rename the new table with the original name. Below is the script.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned](
    [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
    [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
    [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
    [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
    [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
    [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON financialStatementRange(periodenddate);
GO 

INSERT INTO dbo.FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned
SELECT *
FROM dbo.FinancialStatementIds WITH(TABLOCKX);
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.FinancialStatementIds;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned', N'FinancialStatementIds';
GO
```

To slide this 6 year window from 2013-2018 to 2014-2019, remove data from the oldest yearly partition and create a new one for the next future year. In SQL Server 2016 and later, data can be removed from a specific partition using `TRUNCATE TABLE...WITH(PARTITIONS...))`. For example:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.FinancialStatementIds 
WITH (PARTITIONS($PARTITION.financialStatementPartition('20130101')));
```

One must switch into a staging table for this task in SQL Server 2014 and earlier. This is done by creating an aligned staging table with identical schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds_Staging](
       [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
       [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
       [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
       [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
       [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
       [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
       [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
       [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
       [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
       [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
       [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
       [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
       [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON financialStatementRange(periodenddate);
GO
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned_Staging(financialCollectionId);
GO
```

Move data for the oldest year into the staging table and then truncate the staging table to delete the year's data permanently. Once the oldest year partition is empty, remove the boundary from the function. This will merge the first 2 empty partitions into a single empty one.

```
ALTER TABLE FinancialStatementIds
SWITCH PARTITION $PARTITION.financialStatementPartition('20130101') 
TO FinancialStatementIds_Staging PARTITION $PARTITION.financialStatementPartition('20130101');

TRUNCATE TABLE FinancialStatementIds_Staging;

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    MERGE RANGE ('20130101');
GO
```

Then create a partition for the next future year after the new filegroup is created:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT7;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE('20190101');
```

Note there is no requirement to place partitions on different filegroups. Although there can be some performance benefit to place partitions on separate filegroups in specialized use cases when files are placed on separate storage, that is not the case here. Unless you have a specific reason to employ multiple filegroups, you an avoid complexity by placing all partitions on the same filegroup.

Comment: I am bit confused with your answer. I dont see any declaration of filegroups, files and partitionscheme in your answer. Please let me know what the final  solution comprises of as I am new to partitioning and cannot rely on assumptions. Also Please not that this table doesnt have any indexes. I need to partition the table based on the year criteria. Is it really need to have indexes on FinancialStatementIds table ?

Comment: @Tom, there were no changes needed for the filegroups and files. I added the empty partition function and scheme scripts along with how to partition the heap and keep existing data. To avoid assumptions, add the table DDL to your question. I recommend all tables have a clustered index.

Comment: Dan,updated the post with the DDL statement for financialstatementIds table

Comment: As mentioned in the storeprocedure results are stored in the financialstatementsIds table and doesnt have a clustered index. Asumming there is no clustered index on the table, how to go about partioning

Comment: Will a non unique nonclustered index be fine. If that is the case it could be on financialCollectionId.  I could apply it after the data has been migrated to this table via SSIS

Comment: @Tom, yes, you can create a non-unique nonclustered index afterward. The index will be partitioned like the table by default.

Comment: I have one more doubt. In year 2018, will a partition be created for year 2018.  The business is interested only in the last five years. So in year 2018, 2013 is not important.Is the script  above a one time run and forget and the rest is taken care of

Comment: Hi Dan , sorry for coming back late. Your queries run all fine without errors. I have created the partion table , scheme and function. When I try to set the destination to the partioned table I get the following error CurrentUear - 4 has 16 columns that are not mapped to upstream columns. Please delete unmapped columns. I am trying to see if I can dump the records from source directly to the destination table

Comment: @Tom, I'll update my answer for the sliding window retention details later today. The problem with your SSIS package isn't related to partitioning but due to change to a query or table schema used in the package. That can probably be fixed by refreshing/changing the meta-data as indicated in the error. If you can't fix that on your own, I suggest you ask a new question to help with that.

Comment: Dan in your script i can see  ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);  Does that mean when the data is inserted into the table, it is stored in primary file group as well. I thought of initially created 5 partitions excluding primary and storing the data only in those 5 new partitions

Comment: @Tom, the first partition on `PRIMARY` will contain only data before 2013 so that partition should be empty. See the permanent partition of my Table Partitioning Best Practices article: http://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/